# springboot yml map property how to ref bean

Tags: spring, yaml

I want to inject a map in yml file like that ;

```
abc-identify:
  test:
    51L: anhuiAbcIdentifyRule
```

my config class like that

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc-identify")
@Component
@Data
public class AbcIdentifyConfig {

    private Map<Long, IdentifyRule> test;
```

anhuiAbcIdentifyRule is a existing bean in container

```
@Component
public class AnhuiAbcIdentifyRule implements IdentifyRule
```

I tried above setting which not work,how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not support this type of string to bean conversion yet. Your code need to be changed to

```
private Map<Long, String> test;
```

If you want to get bean by rule from properties, there is a workaround.

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc-identify")
public class AbcProperties {
    private Map<Long, String> test;

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, IdentifyRule> identifyRuleMap;

    public IdentifyRule getRule(Long rule){
        String beanName = test.get(rule);
        if(beanName != null){
            return identifyRuleMap.get(beanName);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here `Map<String, IdentifyRule> identifyRuleMap` will contain all beans of `IdentityRule` with keys as `beanName` and values as `bean`.